# SlickGrid enableAddRow

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I want to use the enable AddRow option but I want the new row to be displayed at the top of the grird...Any suggestions; Beloiw is the doco in slickgrid.js.

enableAddRow             - (default false) If true, a blank row will be displayed at the bottom - typing values in that row will add a new one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
function addRowToTheTop(){
    grid.getData().splice(0, 0, {});
    grid.invalidateAllRows();
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
}
```

Call this function to add an empty row at the top of the grid. Not very effective but it works.